# Use findstr to output characters 1-13

Tags: findstr

I have the code: `findstr /B ^121.*.CATDrawing catdrawing.txt`

How to show from the first to thirteenth character?

```
1220112000001A.CATDrawing -> 1220112000001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uuuh... exactly how is that regular expressions `^121.*.CATDrawing` going to match that line with `1220112000001A.CATDrawing`? There is not even `121` in that string ;)

But... going with the assumption you made a typo you could do the following:
(I also made the assumption you wanted this in a batchfile)

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('findstr /B ^121.*.CATDrawing catdrawing.txt') do call :processline %%i
goto :eof

:processline
set line=%*%
echo %line:~0,13%
```

Comment: Didn't know about the substring processing features in windows batch scripting (variable:~N,M). Nice!